# Null hypothesis and alternative hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing

A statistical variable X can have only one of the two following distributions:

```
H0: f0(x) = 0.2-0.02x 
H1: f1(x) = 0.02x
```

In both cases, the support of the statistical variable is:

```
0 <= X <= 10
```

The decision rule for to test the hypothesis, based on a single casual observation, consider the following rejection region for H0:

```
Rif = {X >= 8}
```

Is is required to:

a) Evaluate the significance level (alpha);

b) Evaluate the power of the test (1-beta);

My partial solution: I have written that alpha is the probability to reject H0 when H0 is true (error of first type).  1-beta is the probability to reject H0 when H0 is false (this means, the probability to make the correct decision).

How can I continue to solve?

Thank you very much for considering my request.

Comment: Power is a function on the parameter space. So at which point do you want to evaluate the power?

Comment: The power or sensitivity of a statistical test is the probability that it correctly rejects the null hypothesis (H0) when it is false.

Comment: SOURCE: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power

Answer (score 2):

If $H_0$ is true, then $X$ has the probability density $f_0(x) = 0.2 - 0.02x$ for $0 \le x \le 10$.  So what is $\Pr[X \ge 8]$ under this assumption?  It is $$\Pr[X \ge 8] = \int_{x=8}^{10} f_0(x) \, dx = \ldots?$$

Similarly, under the assumption that $H_1$ is true, what is the probability $\Pr[X \ge 8]$?

Comment: I am not able to calculate it...  In the text of the problem it is not written...

Comment: Under the assumption that H1 is true, I have to integrate f1(x) dx (= 0.02x) from where to where?  x=8 and x=10??

Comment: Spend some time to actually **think** about it.  What is the desired event you wish to see?--to reject $H_0$.  What is the criterion for rejection?--if $X \ge 8$.  What is the assumption?--that $H_1$ is true.  What is the resulting value?  $1-\beta$.

Comment: I am not enough clever to understand what are you writing.  Please explain clearly the solution.

Comment: Perhaps 1-beta is the integrate from x=0 to x=8 of 0.02 x dx ???

Comment: No.  $1-\beta = \Pr[X \ge 8 \mid H_1]$.  It is the probability of rejecting $H_0$ when $H_1$ is true.

Comment: So, 1-beta = integrate from x=8 to x=10 of 0.02 x dx ???